# SVN automaticaly locks a .umap file in UE4

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, putty, unreal-engine4

I'm using SVN as source control for my indie game project, but we are having an issue.

The linux server where the repository are just accept one system user. So i've made several SVN users with SSH Keys and PuTTY. It worked fine, and the commits are made by several different users.

But when i open the UE4 and chance someting on the map, it automatically locks the .umap file. The issue is that it doesn´t lock with my SSH user, it locks with the shared linux user, then when i want to commit, it says that the file is locked by other user.

I've already disabled the "automaticaly check out" in the preferences, but still locking.

Any help on this?

I hope my english was clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "shared linux user"? Do you have an account on the server that you're using to access the repository directly via `file://` protocol?